# Short documents

Tags: document-classes, titles

I need to write a short informal note-type document with a description of my new idea and a few equations - 2 pages max. I use the article document class, but it seems to be an overkill - the title and author take 1/3 of the first page, etc. Could someone recommend a more suitable document type?

Comment: Remove `\maketitle` and do it yourself!

Comment: Along the same lines, I started from [this question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581916/how-do-you-extend-article-document-class-in-latex) to make a modified article class for one of the labs here. It includes a redefinition of `\maketitle`, and can be modified for your specific needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `amsart` or define the title yourself:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large Title of this document

\normalsize A. U. Thor
\end{center}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

Here starts the text.
```